# Can SQL Server trigger disable itself, or be disabled automatically?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a SQL Server trigger that generates unique ID numbers for rows in a particular table.

Every few days, users will tell me that it has stopped generating IDs.  And when I go to the database (SSMS), and look at the trigger, it is disabled.  I enable it, and processing resumes as normal.

As far as I know, the only way to disable a trigger is by an admin going to the trigger, right-click, and select "disable", or running a DDL script that disables it.  No one else in the admin group admits to disabling the trigger.

The Question: Is it possible for a trigger to disable itself if it either loses network connectivity, or gets itself into a recursive loop, or during a backup, or anything else like that?

I need some way to explain how the thing keeps getting disabled.

The internet is strangely silent on this one.

**EDIT:** Log Files seem to have nothing to say about this.  Also, database is part of AAG Availability Group.

EDIT2: Bare bones "code" of the trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Create_Permalink]
   ON  [dbo].[TABLE_NAME_1]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT   * FROM TABLE_NAME_1 
                WHERE   (PermaLink IS NULL or Permalink = '')
                AND     Request_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT Request_ID FROM inserted)
                AND     AC_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT AC_ID FROM inserted)
                AND     Leg_ID  = (SELECT DISTINCT Leg_ID FROM inserted)
    )
    BEGIN

        declare @code nvarchar(32) = '';

        -------------------------------------------------
        -- GENERATE MULTI-PART ALPHANUMERIC IDCODE HERE
        -------------------------------------------------
        -- SET @code = ....Generated Code....


        UPDATE  TABLE_NAME_1 
        SET     PermaLink = @code
        WHERE   (PermaLink IS NULL or Permalink = '')
          AND   Request_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT Request_ID FROM inserted)
          AND   AC_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT AC_ID FROM inserted)
          AND   Leg_ID  = (SELECT DISTINCT Leg_ID FROM inserted)

    END
END
```

I did not write this, so I do not have any say in what it does.

Comment: Please post the trigger body. `No one else in the admin group admits to disabling the trigger.` => [Schema Changes History Report](https://sqlandme.com/2011/07/14/sql-server-management-studio-schema-changes-history-report/) You could also start auditing/extended events session to intercept next occurence.

Comment: Thank you, Lukasz.  The body of the trigger represents significant corporate intellectual rights material.  I would have to significantly obfuscate it, or redact large portions of it.  This question is not so much about the body of the trigger.  It works fine.  I'm asking more about any possible way that it can be disabled short of someone deliberately disabling it.  If no one can offer guidance, I will present a redacted, "edited for space" version of the body.

Comment: Please post the type of trigger, I don't want to know your table names and specific logic. Only type (INSTEAD OF/AFTER) - it is table/database trigger, it is recursive or not. Btw. Are you using replication? Integration tools like SSIS/Informatica?

Comment: It is AFTER INSERT, and yes, database is part of an AAG availability group.

Comment: OK, I see you cannot post more. I suggest to set up audit on that specific trigger and/or extended event. Wait until the same situation reappears and check login/user/session that made this change. It's some background process(data loading) or user.

Comment: Adding some code now.  I did not write this, so I have removed only the bit that actually generates the multi-part varchar code and assigns it to @code.  Here ya go (edit above).

Comment: It seems to be using the opportunity of one row insert to update a number of rows at the same time.  Like everything that hasn't yet been assigned a code gets a code when any one of them are saved.  Not sure.  It looks dodgy to me.

Comment: Are you using some kind of continous deplyoment tool?Like the trigger is disabled every time there is deployment/maintenance task. I would ask your DBA if there have script like `DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS` and when it fails it could not reenable it

Comment: You might check to ascertain if there is a stored procedure  that disables the trigger. 
 It could have a disable command and not re-enable it if an error occurs.

Comment: @B. Seberle.  That was insightful.  I did in fact find a stored procedure that disables this trigger and then does not reenable it.  If you submit this as an answer, I will mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Given that this was just a bug in code I voted to close this as a syntax error.

Comment: I'd second that, Sean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check to ascertain if there is a stored procedure that disables the trigger. It could have a disable command and not re-enable it if an error occurs.

Comment: That indeed was the problem.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.  I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Ah - and the error being raised was probably the one I pointed out! Good solution in two parts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clear error in your trigger. It is assuming that only a single row is updated at any one time, which is not likely to always be the case. If you perform an update that affects multiple rows, then the contents of the `inserted` table will have multiple row, which means this will fail:

```
      AND   Request_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT Request_ID FROM inserted)
      AND   AC_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT AC_ID FROM inserted)
      AND   Leg_ID  = (SELECT DISTINCT Leg_ID FROM inserted)
```

It will return an error indicating that the right side of your equal is not a single value.

I do not know if that is the problem you are seeing, but it might be. You really need to fix this first.

Comment: Nice catch, there.  I will definately take care of that.  I inherited this, so who knows how many similar problems I might be soon having.  ;-)